# JavaScript To Do List crossing out every other item

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I've built this To Do List website:
https://mickanie.github.io/toDoList/
but I've noticed that when I add my own items to the default ones, it only allows me to cross out every other item on the list.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy1e3.png) To be more precise, I cannot cross out item1, item3 and item5 on the enclosed image. Does anyone know why is that and how to fix it?

JavaScript function for crossing out items from the list:

```
const setDoneOnOff = () => {
li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener("click", function(f) {
        f.currentTarget.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}
```

I don't even know if the problem lies there (whole code in site's sources).

Comment: How often are you calling the `setDoneOnOff()` method?

Comment: every time a new li element is created and added to the list

Comment: @Taplar seems to be write. Guessing every time you add a new one you call the method so you add another click handler. click 1 (toggle) and is canceled by the click 2 toggle.  You should only be adding the click event to the new element.

Comment: You could potentially change the li create logic to create the li with a class of `new`.  Then in the binding the querySelectorAll would look for `li.new`, bind on them, and remove the class.

Comment: Otherwise, changing the logic up to use a delegate event listener on the ul for the click of the buttons would remove the need to add bindings for every li created.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, it helped! Now I call setDoneOnOff() only once and when I add new li elements I give them eventListeners directlly and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the eventlistener assignment to the createListElement function:

```
const createListElement = () => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");

  ...

  li.addEventListener("click", function(f) {
     f.currentTarget.classList.toggle("done");
  });

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why people need to do simple things with Javascript.

Info: You can also wrap it with a div, doesn't need to be a form.

```
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" id="abc"><label for="abc">abc</label> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="123"><label for="123">123</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="omg"><label for="omg">omg</label>
</form>

<style>
form{
  display:block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
/* Target only input with a type of checkbox.
 * If the type of checkbox is checked, cross the input and label.
 * Keep in mind that you can NOT cross a checkbox.
 * But it must be there as a "event handler".
 * The plus is a selector that means something like "and" label
 * The input is the checkbox that toggles "checked" and the label is the actual text that gets crossed. */
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/4u7df5z2/4/)

If you don't want the checkboxes add `input[type="checkbox"]{ display:none }` to your style.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/4u7df5z2/3/)

Comment: I like this a lot! Welcome to SO. :) it would be even better if you could [edit] your answer to explain the code.

Comment: I hope it's explained well enough. You can also use something like `input[type="text"]`. It wont affect all "input" but only the ones with type of text.

Answer (score 0):

you should be calling setDoneOnOff method in create element method

```js
const createLiElement = () => {

 createListElement();
 setDoneOnOff();
 addNewDeleteButton();
 showDeleteButton();
 
}
```